# How do you add the AUTO_INCREMENT flag on a column in MYSQL with Peewee?

Tags: mysql, peewee

In PeeWee ORM, you can use `id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)` for a primary key or `id = PrimaryKeyField()`.

If you look at the table that is defined by executing `Model.create_table(fail_silently=True)`, the primary key field is not marked AUTO_INCREMENT.

This is problematic if you have another app that does not use peewee and inserts records into this table.

Can you mark the field AUTO_INCREMENT in MySql or would that lead to errors?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `IntegerField(primary_key=True)` and `PrimaryKeyField()` is that the former does not specify any information about auto-increment, while the latter does. They are *not* the same.

Use `IntegerField(primary_key=True)` when the IDs are coming from some source outside the database.

Use `PrimaryKeyField()` for when you just need a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not necessary to create the Primary Key for a table. Peewee will automatic create the Primary Key for every table with the name id.

But if you want to create it (and I usually do) you create it as:

```
id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
```

Either way the Primary Key id is marked as auto_increment. You can see it using MySQL Workbench or DBeaver or any other way you like it.

Also, I usually create the tables with:

```
mydb = MySQLDatabase(**config)
mydb.connect()
mydb.create_tables([Model1_name, Model2_name, Model3_name], safe=True)
```

Of course the

```
Model.create_table(fail_silently=True)
```

also works for a single table without problem (I checked it)

Comment: maybe I'm missing the primary_key=True parameter and that's why it does not mark it as AUTO_INCREMENT. I will try that thanks.

Comment: I assumed the tables are InnoDB. Or they are MyISAM?

Comment: You don't need primary_key=True.

Comment: Are you sure you're using PrimaryKeyField and not IntegerField instead?